# Axiom of choice and specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Halmos' Naive set theory and I have the next question.

By definition if $ \{X_{i}\}_{i \in I} $ is a family of sets, the cartesian product of the family is the set of all families that $\{x_{i}\}$ with $x_{i} \in X_{i}$.
But by definition, a family is a function from $I$ to a set $X$.
A function from $I$ to $X$ is a subset of $I \times X$, so a element of $\mathcal{P}(I \times X)$.
Why I can not do $\{ z \in I \times \cup_{i \in I}X_{i} | z=(i,x_{i}), x_{i} \in I \}$ (*using the specification axiom*) to obtain a element of $\times_{i}X_{i}$ without using axiom of choice?

Comment: But, you are using choice! Where would you otherwise get the $x_i$ from?

Comment: In the same way that you say $\{z \in X \times Y | z=(x,y), x \in X, y \in Y \}$ that is how the cartesian product of two sets is builded.

Comment: I think that the axiom of choice is to guarantee that the set is non-empty. But in that case, if I define a function for example $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x):=x+2$, I also need the axiom of choice?

Comment: Why the set $\{z \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} | z=(x,x+2)\}$ is not empty?

Comment: One of the [many $\mathsf{ZF}$-equivalent formulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents) of $\mathsf{AC}$ is: "The Cartesian product of any family of nonempty sets is nonempty". By contrast, the other set you mention has obvious elements such as $(0,\,2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that
$$
\Big\{ z \in I \times \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \mid z = (i, x_i), \ x_i \in I \Big\}
$$
is a typographical error, and that what you meant was something more like this:
\begin{gather*}
\Big\{ z \in I \times \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \mid (\exists i \in I) \ (\exists x \in X_i) \ z = (i, x) \Big\} \\ =
\Big\{ (i, x) \mid i \in I, \ x \in X_i \Big\} =
\bigcup_{i \in I} (\{i\} \times X_i).
\end{gather*}
The trouble is that, if this is indeed the set that you meant to define, then it is a disjoint union of the sets $X_i,$ and is not an element of $\prod_{i \in I} X_i,$ except in the uninteresting case where for all $i,$ $X_i$ has only one element.

Comment: And now you apply specification axiom to $\cup_{i \in I}(\{i\} \times X_{i})$ to obtein a element $\cup_{i \in} (\{i\} \times x_{i})$.

Comment: I think that the problem is guarantee that $\{z \in I \times \cup_{i \in I}X_{i} | z=(i,x_{i}),x_{i} \in I\}$ is non empty.

Comment: Wikipedia say that in Infinite Cartesian Product.

Comment: In applying the specification axiom to $\bigcup_{i \in I} (\{i\} \times X_i),$ what defining property are you proposing to use?

Comment: Suposse you know that exists a element $x_{i} \in X_{i}$ $\forall i \in I$. can you say $\{ z \in \cup_{i \in I}(\{i\} \times X_{i}) | z=(i,x_{i}) \}$?

Comment: A property of the same style that you use for obtein the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x+2$ for the set $\{z \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: You could indeed use as the defining property something like $(\exists i \in I) \ z = (i, x_i),$ but only if you have a formula that defines an element $x_i \in X_i$ for every $i \in I$ - and in such a case, you do not need to employ (or indeed prove) the Axiom of Choice!

Comment: Then, for example, we know that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is non empty without axiom of choice?

Comment: Because we can fix a $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for example $0$, and then $\{z \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} | z=(y,0) y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (I'm assuming that Choice isn't needed to construct $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place! I'm pretty sure it isn't - I feel pretty silly for even mentioning this as a possibility - but I haven't actually checked.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The Specification Axiom requires a specific formula (written in the first-order language of set theory).  In practice, these formulas are usually highly abbreviated, so it can be easy to lose sight of when you do or do not really have a first-order formula.

So for example, in $$ \{ z \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \; \mid \; \exists \, y \in \mathbb R , \; z = ( y , 0 ) \} \text , $$ the formula $ \exists \, y \in \mathbb R , \; z = ( y , 0 ) $ needs an explicit quantifier to explain how the variable $ y $ is introduced, while the term $ \mathbb R $ has to be defined (which I'll assume has already been done) and $ ( y , 0 ) $ has to be defined in terms of $ y $, and even $ \exists \, y \in \mathbb R , \; \cdots $ is an abbreviation for $ \exists \, y , \; y \in \mathbb R \; \wedge \; \cdots $.

We can also do $$ \{ z \in I \times \bigcup _ { i \in I } X _ i \; \mid \; \exists \, i \in I , \; \exists \, x \in X _ i , \; z = ( i , x ) \} $$ (from Calum's answer) as long as the variables that appear freely in it, which are $ I $ and $ X $, have been introduced (and assuming that we've already defined what $ \times $, $ \bigcup $, and attaching a subscript mean).  (Note that the family $ X $ is formally a function, that is a set of ordered pairs with unique first components, whose domain is $ I $, so that $ X _ i $ means the second component of the unique ordered pair in this set whose first component is $ i $.)  And we can even do $$ \{ z \in I \times \bigcup _ { i \in I } X _ i \; \mid \; \exists \, i \in I , \; z = ( i , x _ i ) \} $$ as long as $ I $, $ X $, and $ x $ have been introduced.  But now you can hopefully see the problem; you need to already have the family $ x $ before you can write this down!  (And then if you have it, the set that you've written down is equal to $ x $.)

ETA:  David Hilbert once proposed an extended language for first-order logic with, for each formula $ \phi [ x ] $ with a specified free variable, a term $ \varepsilon \, x , \; \phi [ x ] $.  And this has an axiom to go with it, saying that if $ \exists \, x , \; \phi [ x ] $ is true, then $ \phi [ \varepsilon \, x , \; \phi [ x ] ] $ is also true.  So $ \varepsilon \, x , \; \phi [ x ] $ may be read ‘some $ x $ (if any exists) such that $ \phi [ x ] $’.  Using this language, you can write $$ \{ z \in I \times \bigcup _ { i \in I } X _ i \; \mid \; \exists \, i \in I , \; z = ( i , ( \varepsilon \, x , \; x \in X _ i ) ) \} \text . $$  In other words, you can define $ x _ i $ as $ \varepsilon \, x , \; x \in X _ i $; and if you already know that $ \exists \, x , \; x \in X _ i $, then you can conclude that $ x _ i \in X _ i $.  But it's well known that the Axiom of Choice is provable in set theory built on first-order logic with Hilbert's $ \varepsilon $, so this is no surprise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Could you recommend me a book where I can learn more about first-order formula and set theory?